# Why this piece of NodeJs code has given a BSOD on Win7?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, binance

I'm actually playing with blockchains in nodejs (with WebStorm IDE).
The following code has produced a "BAD_POOL_CALLER" bluescreen on Win7. Could you know why ? Thanks.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

// Parcourir tous les blocs entre bloc courant et bloc-1000 et lister toutes les transactions de chaque bloc
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(blockNumber => {
    for(let i=blockNumber-1000; i<=blockNumber; i++) {
        web3.eth.getBlock(i).then(block => {
            block.transactions.forEach(function(t) {
                web3.eth.getTransaction(t).then(transaction => {
                    console.log(i + ' ' + transaction.hash + ' ' + transaction.from + ' ' + transaction.to)
                })
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: It should not do that. Probably something broken with your Windows, as only faulty kernel drivers can cause Windows bluescreen.

Comment: Sorry it is not Win10 but Win7. My Windows is clean, I often reinstall my operating system and it is always clean. I think that the reason might be a huge number of threads (<=> a kind of "promise" problem for which I have not found the solution yet).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yes I think you are right about that. This BSOD has only happened on Win7 and seems not to happen on Win10, so this issue might be due to the Win7 operating system itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using the setTimeout function has improved the processing... Not sure but it seems to work a little better now. This is far from perfect because I'm facing another issue but it seems I'm on the right path :

```
// Parcourir tous les blocs entre bloc courant et bloc-1000 et lister 
// toutes les transactions de chaque bloc, avec temporisation de 5 
// secondes entre chaque bloc.

let index = 0
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(blockNumber => {
    for (let i = blockNumber - 1000; i <= blockNumber; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(index) {
            getBlockInfo(i).then()
            console.log('next')
            console.log("index=" + index)
        }, 5000 * index, index)
        index = index+1
    }
});

async function getBlockInfo(i) {
    await web3.eth.getBlock(i).then(block => {
        block.transactions.forEach(function (t) {
            web3.eth.getTransaction(t).then(transaction => {
                console.log(i + ' ' + transaction.hash + ' ' + transaction.from + ' ' + transaction.to)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('erreur')
            })
        })
    }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
}
```